# How to average score from different elements

Tags: r

I have a data list look like this:

```
AD  Score
k01 0.423045866
k01 0.480309111
k01 0.725338203
k01 0.619097222
k01 0.480309111
k01 0.619097222
k01 0.423045866
k05 0.650419719
i03 0.932386364
j02 0.530082418
j02 0.270337302
j02 0.270337302
i03 0.59271728
j02 0.270337302
j02 0.530082418
```

[Data source](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9izMV2W4zC3MG9ldHZyMWpvX2s)

I want to average all the score from different ADs. It should look like:

```
AD  Main_Score
a01 0.002384921
a02 0.000745303
a03 0.009494517
a04 0.002697162
a05 0.008923368
a06 0.010729049
b05 0.008715195
c01 0.002960632
c02 0.009725276
c04 0.40982829
d01 0.007238207
```

Comment: `aggregate(Score ~ AD, data, mean)`

Comment: Something went wrong with marking the duplicate. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21982987/mean-per-group-in-a-data-frame) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23566106/r-take-the-average-of-values-with-criteria) are correct alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, list(avg = mean(Score)), by = AD]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend the `dplyr` package.

```
require(dplyr)
data %>% 
 group_by(AD) %>% 
 summarize(avg = mean(Score))
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table)
dt <-  data.table(ur_data)
dt[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = "AD"]
```